# How to create a new file copying a header file with the expanded macro

Tags: c, gcc, build, eclipse-cdt, labview

I have a header file with a Macro that declare functions. I need to import my header file to the `LabView`, but his cant read the Macro, so cant identify my declareted functions.

I want to generate another code file with the expanded Macro during the build.

Has a build configuration to do it on Eclipse?

Exemple:

The Macro:

```
#define FUNCTION_SIGNATURE(TYPE, RET, FUNCTION) \
    RET TYPE##_##FUNCTION(int port, char* id)   \
```

`header.h`

```
FUNCTION_SIGNATURE(TEST, int, init);
```

I need a file that contains the expanded Macro is like:

```
int  TEST_init(int port, char* id);
```

**OBS:**

- My project is a shared library (DLL)
- I'm using a `Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Development`
- The compiler is `gcc`

**Edit**
It's a DLL that I import into labview, when importing it needs a header to link with the DLL's functions, and here's my problem, it can't expand the macro to read the function declarations, so I'd like of a way to pass the expanded macros to another file, the labview undestand just the expanded macro. This problem is only to the header file.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Your macro is doing what you expect. And what's wrong with typing it normally? By the way, you are probably using gcc compiler.

Comment: I rewrite the question @BarmakShemirani

Comment: I don't know if it can be done. Are these your own c functions? I mean, if it relates to MinGW, it probably has lots of macros for Windows APIs, probably LabView can't handle that anyway.

Comment: It's a DLL that I import into labview, when importing it needs a header to link with the DLL's functions, and here's my problem, it can't expand the macro to read the function declarations, so I'd like of a way to pass the expanded macros to another file, the labview undestand just the expanded macro. This problem is only to the header file.

Comment: You can tell GCC to print the result after preprocessing, by the option `-E`, which will expand all macros. Save this output in a differently named header, derived from its original name, for example "library-expanded.h" and feed this into LabView. You can try to use pre-build or post-build commands in Eclipse, depending on your kind of project, or add this header as an extra target.

Comment: @thebusybee Can ou show me a example? I tryied but without success.

Comment: Where exactly do you stumble? Please add this to your question.

Comment: @thebusybee I got it! Thanks, using the `gcc -E header.h -o header_ex.h` command line it builds the expansions correctly, and it works in Labview. My problem was that I putting the setup wrong in Eclipse, and I still don't know how to put it correctly to do that when building the project. Do you know how put to run this comand during the  eclipse build?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the kind of your project. I never use managed projects, instead I write my makefiles manually, for multiple reasons. If you use a hand-written makefile, simply add an appropriate target and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain a preprocessed header file, use GCC's option `-E`. It produces an output after the preprocessing stage, which includes the expansion of all macros.

`gcc -E library.h -o library_expanded.h` will do the trick. Adjust the filenames to your liking.

To automate this in your build, use an appropriate build command of your IDE, or add the expanded header to your Makefile. I suggest to run this command only if the build of your library succeeded.